# Is making the UIView disabled an exact way while running a method in the background according to apple's standards?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I used to disable current view while a method is running in the background(may be an API Call) asynchrnolsly.But as per the Human Interface Guidline I understood that disabling the View while a method runs in the BG, is not a right way.So If I need to avoid user accessing different IBActions while some thing performs in the back ground what is the best method?

Comment: y cant u use uialertview to disable view

Comment: @g because it causes a bad UX.

Comment: "So If I need to avoid user accessing different IBActions" - the redesign your code, you should not need that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Consider the case that I have two Buttons with each IBActions.When I tapped q button a method runs in the BG.If the user could tap the other button only after completing previous method done what is the way?